# LAT and LNG not showing on input form in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation

Am using the below code to get LAT and LNG of my current location to display it in the input form but for some reason, it does not display my LAT and LNG as wanted, rather it will display the LAT and LNG in a flash and disappear. I tried to change my browser permission to allow Location and still shows in a flash and disappears. Can anyone help? Below is my code:

```
<form>  

<button onclick="onFormSubmit()">GET CURRENT LOCATION</button>



<script type="text/javascript">
function onGeoSuccess (position) {
        var lat = position.coords.latitude;
        var lng = position.coords.longitude;

        // NEXT 2 LINES WILL SET VALUE OF RESPECTIVE INPUTS
        document.getElementById('lat').value = lat;
        document.getElementById('lng').value = lng;

        // MAKE API CALL HERE, OR ANY OTHER NEXT STEPS
    }

    function onGeoError (err) {
        console.error("Error while trying to get position", err);
    }

    function onFormSubmit () {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onGeoSuccess, onGeoError);
        } else {
            alert('GeoLocation not supported or not allowed');
        }
    }</script>

              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="lat" class="form-control" id="lat" placeholder="Your Latitude" data-msg="Please enter your latitude">
                <div class="validate"></div>
              </div>

<div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="lng" class="form-control" id="lng" placeholder="Your Longitude" data-msg="Please enter your Longitude">
                <div class="validate"></div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="subject" class="form-control" id="contact-subject" placeholder="Subject" data-rule="minlen:4" data-msg="Please enter at least 8 chars of subject">
                <div class="validate"></div>
              </div>


</form>
```

I just want to get the LAT and LNG display on the input form with each of it ID but I don't know what am doing wrong. It is not showing as wanted.

Comment: Since the coordinates are displayed for a split second, it sounds like the success callback is invoked. Are you getting any error messages in your console?

Comment: no error, could this be as a result of my website template?

Comment: Dunno. What does it print when you log `position` first thing in your `onGeoSuccess` callback?

Comment: yes it does, I tried to add "onFormSubmit" to the <body onload = "onFormSubmit"> </body> and it work but I don't want it to load the current location without clicking on the "GET CURRENT LOCATION"

Comment: *What* does `position` print?

Comment: It prints my LAT and LNG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I trace back my code and troubleshoot the error and discovered this was simply because I used `<button onclick="onFormSubmit()">GET CURRENT LOCATION</button>` instead of `<button onclick=" return onFormSubmit()">GET CURRENT LOCATION</button>`. When I call just `onFormSubmit` on `onclick` for some reason it appears for a split second and disappears but when I call `return onFormSubmit()` on `onclick` everything works perfectly.

Comment: Ok but that doesn't explain the underlying issue. Why would the lat and lng suddenly display when the `onFormSubmit` is called by something else and at a different time?

Comment: Do you have a better solution to this? I am open to a better solution, am not sure why it appears and display. When I created a simple HTML page without CSS, it works perfectly but when I add CSS, Javascript, and others to it then it disappears.

Comment: It's hard suggesting a solution without understanding the problem first. What's your CSS? Have you narrowed it down to the CSS statement that causes the issue?

Comment: What part of the CSS should I look at? Should I paste my CSS here?

Comment: Yea paste it here and also start doing a binary search through it: remove half your CSS code, see if you can still reproduce the error. If not, check the other half. If yes, halve it again. And so on. Until you have found the line that causes the issue.

Comment: I just updated my code and added the CSS. Kindly look at it.

Comment: I can't look through all of that, please perform the binary search that I have described, it should take less than ten steps to find it.

Comment: So I went through my code and I trouble to find out it is not the CSS causing the error but the way I called the javascript function at onclick. Have updated my answer with the solution.